# WHQL driver test INF error

Tags: windows, driver, wdf

When I run WHQL test "DF - Validate driver INF against component specific requirements" it gives me this error:

> The inf C:\Windows\Inf\oem10.inf had an error at line 103.
>   Flag 0x10000 must be specified for 'CoInstallers32' registry key.

Line 103 of oem10.inf:

> HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010008,"WdfCoInstaller01011.dll,WdfCoInstaller"

As you can see flag 0x**1**0000 is specified in my value 0x000**1**0008. When I change the value from 0x00010008 to 0x00010000 the test validates correctly. Problem is I cannot install the driver on Windows Vista when 0x00010000 is specified instead of 0x00010008.

Why is this? Is this a HLK bug? The target system for the WHQL test the error is ocurring on is Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is definitely misleading. It should be "**VALUE** 0x10000 must be specified for 'CoInstallers32' registry key. ..." instead of "**FLAG** 0x10000 must be specified ..."

Anyways the solution is to use Coinstallers32 only once per INF file with "0x00010000" as value and to specify multiple coinstallers as parameters like (example):

```
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WudfUpdate_$UMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll", "WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll, WdfCoinstaller", "WinUsbCoinstaller2.dll"
```